# Custom type entity hidden without pass the class always

Tags: forms, symfony

Currently i'm using a custom Type in some forms, basically becomes an "id to entity" and "entity to id" thanks to [bjo3rnf](https://gist.github.com/bjo3rnf/4061232), but i dont want pass every time the `class` and for laziness and other problems.

I know if when i add a field to the FormBuilder and pass null in the type symfony guess the correct type, I think it is using the property `data_class` of the main form i want do the same thing for guess the correct class but i dont know how to access to the parent `data_class`

the [@jamek answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26630849/816721) works some cases others fails

Example:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Person {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(length=150, type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var City
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="City")
     */
    protected $city;
}

class City {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(length=150, type="string")
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

in the controller when i want to create the new object

```
$object = new Person();
$form = $formFactory->create(new PersonType(), $object);

$form->submit($request); // here fails because cant convert city_id to City object
```

works only for a exist object

```
$object = $manager->find('Person', $id);
$form = $formFactory->create(new PersonType(), $object);

$form->submit($request); // here works fine property is a object and the code get_class($builder->getData()) get the correct City class
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @Matteo that has the same issue need pass 'class' option i want avoid  that

Answer (score 4):

If i understand want you want u should change in buildForm method:

```
$transformer = new EntityToIdTransformer($this->objectManager, $options['class']);
```

to

```
 $transformer = new EntityToIdTransformer($this->objectManager, get_class($builder->getData()));
```

And remove required from Option resolver for a class

Comment: only work in some cases others `$builder->getData() == null` resulting a error. example if the entity in this property has a object (when editing) works but otherwise is a error

Comment: So you have to check data is object and then get class

Comment: that's right but if is null how to get the correct object

Comment: send some example when it's a null

Comment: this answer is not the solution :(

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the construct in the Person class

```html
class Person {
    
    ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->city = new City();
    }
}
```

Comment: this maybe solve the problem but i'm changing the 'class' parameter for editing all my entities contructors maybe isnt a good idea other bundles can use the solution without change her constructor entities